# What may cause the text of a message created with the Message module to be empty?

Tags: 7, message-subscribe

I have installed the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to log activities, and set it up following [these instructions](http://webwash.net/tutorials/log-site-activity-message-and-rules).

All steps look good, and message (admin/content/message) is created after I added new content. But, the message's TEXT field is empty.

Also, `Message: Render message (Get text)` field in related View is also empty, and `SHOW NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR` is triggered.

I enabled message_example module come with message, same result.

Is there anything wrong with my options?

Comment: Have you checked if permissions conf is needed?

Comment: I am using ADMINISTRATOR, so not the permission.

Comment: @Rotem I checked Message class, and it turns out that I have a wrong language code, 'cause I set administer language to English other than default language. It works now after I set language back to default.

Comment: I think you need to give message permission to administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather typical issue in multi-language sites. A variation (not duplicate) of your question is what is described in "[Rules - Set language of message notification](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/130333/39516)".

A possible solution (work-around?) is what you wrote in your own comment below your question, i.e.:

> I checked Message class, and it turns out that I have a wrong language code, 'cause I set administer language to English other than default language. It works now after I set language back to default.

Another solution is to indicate the language in which the message is to be created.